# init value n custom Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this custom editor:

```cs
 [CustomEditor(typeof(Fluid3D), true)]
        public class Fluid3DEditor : Editor
        {
            public override void OnInspectorGUI()
            {
                //this method for create default monoBehavior fields
                //that i make it in base class (Fluid3D)
                DrawDefaultInspector();
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
    
                SerializedProperty zz = serializedObject.FindProperty("Particle Radius");
    
                // Debug.Log(zz.intValue);
                Fluid3D fluid3D = (Fluid3D)target;
    
                switch (fluid3D.initParticleWay)
                {
                    case InitParticleWay.SPHERE:
                        Sphere(ref fluid3D);
    
                        break;
                    case InitParticleWay.CUBE:
                        Cube(ref fluid3D);
                        break;
                }
    
            }
    
            void Sphere(ref Fluid3D fluid3D)
            {
                fluid3D.BallRadius = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Sphere Radius", fluid3D.BallRadius);
            }
    
            void Cube(ref Fluid3D fluid3D)
            {
                fluid3D.ParticleRadius = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Particle Radius", fluid3D.ParticleRadius);
                fluid3D.separationFactor = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Sepreation Factor", fluid3D.separationFactor);
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Volume", fluid3D.Volume.ToString());
}
```

and the init value in class Field3D is

```cs
private float ballRadius = 0.1f; 
public float separationFactor = 1.4f;
private float particleRadius = 0.15f;
```

when I edit the values from inspector before run the Scene
the values doesn't changed, just change while the game but I am need changing before the game started.

[image]

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two variables ball radius and particle radius are private. Serialize them:

```cs
[SerializeField] private float ballRadius = 0.1f; 
[SerializeField] public float separationFactor = 1.4f;
[SerializeField] private float particleRadius = 0.15f;
```

Comment: actually i make my fields is HideInInspector ,so i make both hide and serialize for my fields.
```[HideInInspector, SerializeField] private float ballRadius = 0.1f; 

[SerializeField, SerializeField] public float separationFactor = 1.4f;

[SerializeField, SerializeField] private float particleRadius = 0.15f; ```

Comment: When you define a variable through unity editor. Privates can also be displayed but can not be changed in the editor.